# Compare arrays of custom objects in Swift?

Tags: swift, compare, comparable

I have objects which implement `Сomparable` protocol:

```
class SomeClass: Comparable {
    ...//comparable implementation
}
```

So now I can for example sort `[SomeClass]`.

But if I want to compare arrays of such objects?

`Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to two '[SomeClass]' operands`

How to solve this issue?

Comment: What makes one array "less than" another array? There isn't exactly one reasonable answer to that question.

Comment: Like comparing of strings by symbols - compare arrays by comparing pairs of elements. If elements in previous comparisons were equal and there is not enough elements in one of the arrays then compare arrays by item count.
Note: the question is more about how to make `[SomeClass]` comparable than about a concrete algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [`lexicographicallyPrecedes(_:)` method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/lexicographicallyprecedes(_:)) of `Sequence`.

There is also a [`lexicographicallyPrecedes(_:by:)` method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/lexicographicallyprecedes(_:by:)) that takes a comparison function, in case your elements aren't `Comparable` (or you don't want to use the conformance).

Comment: thanks but maybe is there another solution to override the algo which `lexicographicallyPrecedes` uses? It allows to compare elements only but not the sequences by itself